# Working Chainway C72 UHF sample code for Android 11 version

Tags: flutter, xamarin, rfid, android-11

From what I can gather Chainway changed the API to their hardware library with the move from Android 7 to Android 11 causing almost all the current packages for different frameworks out there to no longer work. Does anyone have working sample code for the Chainway C72 running on Android 11 other than this buggy Android Studio [sample project](https://www.chainway.net/download/SDKs-Android/demo-uhf_as.rar)? Biggest preference would be Xamarin/Maui or Flutter, but honestly any stable code would be greatly appreciated.

**What we've tried:**
We have noticed that most of the libraries use a deprecated API class called RFIDWithUHF.
We contacted Chainway technical support and they provided us with firmware update files and mentioned that we should use RFIDWithUHFUart class instead. They provided an Android Studio [sample project](https://www.chainway.net/download/SDKs-Android/demo-uhf_as.rar), if you restart the device and run the project you are able to scan RFID tags, but it is extremely buggy and quickly crashes. Closing the app and restarting it unfortunately does not recover it from this state even though the code does a free and initialise on startup. You have to reboot the device to get it out of this state.

We attempted to use the following packages/libraries with the following results:

- Using these three Nuget packages on Xamarin [1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Smartway.Device.Chainway) [2](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chainway.Light.SDK) [3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Chainway_C72_DeviceAPI_Xamarin) - Initialize method always return false and we're unable to scan tags
- Using this flutter [package](https://pub.dev/packages/uhf_c72_plugin) - We got the following printouts on our console:

```
An Observatory debugger and profiler on C72 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:61316/iEK5kGMghqQ=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on C72 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:61316/iEK5kGMghqQ=/
I/DeviceAPI_DeviceCon(30538): getDeviceInfoFromFile configPath=/storage/emulated/0/PDAConfig.txt
D/DeviceAPI_DeviceCon(30538): cw.model2:
D/DeviceAPI_DeviceCon(30538): cw.model:mtk.6765.c72
D/DeviceAPI_DeviceCon(30538): 最终cw.model:mtk.6765.c72
I/DeviceAPI_DeviceCon(30538): model=C72,uartPath=/dev/ttyMT3,uartPath_Fingerprint=/dev/ttyMT0,uartPath_RFID=
I/DeviceAPI_DeviceCon(30538): getModel() model=C72
D/DeviceAPI(30538): UHF device = C72
D/DeviceAPI(30538): UHF_Init----------->DevIsOpen = 1
D/DeviceAPI(30538): UHF uart = /dev/ttyMT3
D/DeviceAPI_SerialPort(30538): [SerialPort_Open] [2]: No such file or directory
D/DeviceAPI(30538): UHF uhf_uart_fd = -1
I/DeviceAPI_UHF(30538): init() Uart = /dev/ttyMT3
E/DeviceAPI_UHF(30538): init() err UHFOpenAndConnect result:-1
E/DeviceAPI_UHF(30538): startInventory() err :-1
```

- This react [package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/c72-rfid-scanner) - Get the following build error:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.   
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* Where:
Build file 'C:\Repos\Sandbox\ReactNative\c72ScannerReact\node_modules\c72-rfid-scanner\android\build.gradle' line: 23

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':c72-rfid-scanner'.
> Plugin with id 'maven' not found.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':c72-rfid-scanner'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle
```

- We've also tried all the example code [here](https://www.chainwayeurope.com/en/download#c72) with no luck either.

Comment: Did you find out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the [rfid_c72_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/rfid_c72_plugin) Flutter package that seems to support the Android 11 version of the C72 well. Although whenever I press the hardware buttons it seems like the firmware crashes and I have to reboot the device. Not sure if our device or firmware version might be faulty.

Comment: Hi, are you using android studio or flutter?

Comment: I ended up using Flutter as I am more familiar with Flutter than vanilla Android.

Comment: @CVStrydom , do you still experience issue when trying to initialize the RFID reader?

Comment: @YounesBelouche , no thankfully it seems initialisation works well with the Flutter package. I had to park the project though as higher priority projects came up.

Answer (score 0):

I am also looking at the same device (Xamarin).  I was not able to get the samples online working, but after contacting tech support I received working sample code.

Comment: That's great news. Was the sample code for Xamarin?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @paulc can you share the working Xamarin version ? Appreciate it